# Catboost Categorical Features Handling Options (CTR settings)?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, categorical-data

I am working with a dataset with large number of categorical features (>80%) predicting a continuous target variable (i.e. Regression). I have been reading quite a bit about ways to handle categorical features. And learned that one-hot encoding I have been using in past is really bad idea especially when it comes to lots of categorical features with many levels (read these [post](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/), and [this](https://blog.myyellowroad.com/using-categorical-data-in-machine-learning-with-python-from-dummy-variables-to-deep-category-66041f734512)).

While I've come across methods like target-based encoding (smoothing) of categorical features often based on mean of target values for each feature perhaps this [post/kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/ogrellier/python-target-encoding-for-categorical-features) in Kaggle. Still I am struggling to find a more concrete way till I found [CatBoost](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/) an open-source gradient boosting on decision trees released last year by Yandex group. They seem to offer extra statistical counting options for categorical features likely much more efficient than simple one-hot encoding or smoothing.

**The problem** is the documentation is not helpful how to set ***CTR settings***. I have tried different ways but it just does not work. The doc says *CTR setting* as ***simple_ctr***, to be given as ([CTR setting section](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list-docpage/)):

```
['CtrType[:TargetBorderCount=BorderCount][:TargetBorderType=BorderType][:CtrBorderCount=Count][:CtrBorderType=Type][:Prior=num_1/denum_1]..[:Prior=num_N/denum_N]',
 'CtrType[:TargetBorderCount=BorderCount][:TargetBorderType=BorderType][:CtrBorderCount=Count][:CtrBorderType=Type][:Prior=num_1/denum_1]..[:Prior=num_N/denum_N]',
  ...]
```

Here is a super simple example, the data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import catboost
data = [{'profit': '342','country': 'holland','account': 'Jones LLC', 'saving': 150, 'debt': -60, 'age': 28},
         {'profit': '875','country': 'germany','account': 'Alpha Co',  'saving': 200, 'debt': -10, 'age': 42},
         {'profit': '127','country': 'italy','account': 'Blue Inc',  'saving': 50,  'debt': -300,  'age': 38 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is a simple Catboost Regressor:

```
X_train = df.drop(['profit'],axis=1)
Y_train = df['profit']
categorical_features_indices = [0,2]

train_pool = catboost.Pool(X_train, Y_train, cat_features=categorical_features_indices)

model = catboost.CatBoostRegressor(
    depth=3,
    iterations=5,
    eval_metric='RMSE',
    simple_ctr=None)

model.fit(train_pool);
```

The **simple_ctr**, one of CTR settings, is the problem!! It is pity because it looks like it the package offers various methods, so far no way to access them.

**UPDATE Aug. 9th, 2018:** A few days ago I raised this problem to Catboost developer, see [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/436), and they opened a ticket for it to provide a tutorial.

Comment: Here is the description about catboost on categorical vaiable: https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic-docpage/

Comment: Yes, I know the link; it gives a detailed theoretical description. Yet not enough description on how to use it is given; I mean practical usage instructions. I have have tried it a few months ago and it was not straightforward.

Comment: I am currently only using the one_hot_max_size param and my understanding is that everything that is not one hot encoded, will be encoded using target mean expanding encoding. I am looking forward to the additional official documentation to understand the ctr settings better and how I can play with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that in order to set the `ctr` parameters and all the components one should pass a list of strings, each string should contain the `ctrType` and one of its component:

- The first word of the string should be a `ctrType` for example `Borders:` (click [here](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list.html) for catboost parameters)
- Then one component of the `ctrType` should follow. For example `TargetBorderType=5`.
- All together `'Borders:TargetBorderType=5'`.
- Repeat the procedure to set an other component and add the new string to the list.

Example with two components set:

```
simple_ctr = ['Borders:TargetBorderType=Uniform', 'Borders:TargetBorderCount=50']
```

Comment: It works, thanks for the explanation, and sorry for taking a long time to get back to double-check it, slipped though my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the format provided like below:

```
['CtrType[:TargetBorderCount=BorderCount][:TargetBorderType=BorderType][:CtrBorderCount=Count][:CtrBorderType=Type][:Prior=num_1/denum_1]..[:Prior=num_N/denum_N]'

['BinarizedTargetMeanValue[:TargetBorderCount=1][:TargetBorderType=Uniform][:CtrBorderCount=5][:CtrBorderType=Uniform][:Prior=1]']
```

Comment: Is this an answer?  It feels more like a question/comment.

Comment: @Interested_Programmer: It does not work, try it yourself in the example I just provided. Have you tested it or you simply found it in the documentation?

Comment: I apologize @StephenRauch. I was unable to run my notebook but found it usable in other functions to follow the format. In hindsight, I should have added it as a comment. I am also waiting for the creators to put out the new tutorial.

Comment: also this works.  simple_ctr=['BinarizedTargetMeanValue'])

Comment: Thanks. But as you shown it only works as simple_ctr=['BinarizedTargetMeanValue'])! The other options can not be fed like [:TargetBorderCount=BorderCount] etc. If you know how to feed others together with CtrType, let me know.